# I need to get two separate lines for evens and odds, but the catch is, I can use only one while loop

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, jgrasp

This is my code:

```
int numb = 50;
int odd;
int even;
while (numb <= 100) {
    if (numb % 2 == 0) {
        even = numb;
        System.out.println(even);
        System.out.print(", ");
        numb++;
    }
    System.out.println("");
    if (numb % 2 != 0) {
        odd = numb;
        System.out.print(odd);
        System.out.print(", ");
        numb++;
    }
}
```

So far, it prints two columns of answers but i need to separate rows of evens and odds. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why not just add the evens and odds in two separate arrays or lists, and then print these two arrays/lists at the end, after the while-loop ends?

Comment: I cannot use arrays, i'd love to but cannot. That is a condition of this program in a whole.

Comment: @ChthonicProject printing this array/list in a good format would probably require another loop. Simplest way would be to just use two Stringbuilders where you append the evens/odds and print those after the while loop is done.

Comment: you don't need the second if, you can just use else. also, numb++ doesn't need to be repeated - you're going to do that whatever the result of the if statement. and, you don't really need variables odd and even.

Comment: @pecks I tried removing the second if and used an else, it made me remove the print statement to separate the lines. How else can have that line separation?

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS The toString() method in Java 8 already uses StringBuilder to do this. For older versions, your argument is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use two `StringBuilder` and keep appending `sOdd` and `sEven` to respective `StringBuilder` and after the loop you can print them.

Something similar

```
StringBuilder sOdd = new StringBuilder("");
StringBuilder sEven = new StringBuilder("");

while (numb <= 100) {
    if (numb % 2 == 0) {
        sEven.append(numb).append(",");
    }
    if (numb % 2 != 0) {
        sOdd.append(numb).append(",");
    }
   numb++;
}

System.out.println(sEven.toString()+"\n"+sOdd.toString());
```

Comment: Why using the "String", if we can use other mutable string classes like "StringBuilder" or "StringBuffer".

Comment: @Punit true. As OP was not specific. I can change it, if you wish ;)

Comment: Perfect, that is running perfectly, I did not know that strings can work that way. I am a low intermediate java user so it is good to know they can work as such.

Answer (score 0):

I f you're particular about single while loop and constant extra space you can do this:

```
int numb1 = 50,numb2=51;
while (numb1 <= 100 || numb2<=100) 
{
if (numb1<=100) 
{
    System.out.print(numb1);
    System.out.print(", ");
    numb1=numb1+2;
}


else if (numb2<=100) 
{
    if(numb2==51)
    System.out.println();

    System.out.print(numb2);
    System.out.print(", ");
    numb2=numb2+2;
}
}
```